# Is there way to configure the z-axis of a widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have two custom pop up buttons in a row which are siblings made from stacks. Each stack has a toggle button and a pop up menu. The toggle button opens the pop up menu.

The popup of one stack should cover the toggle button of the other stack, but that's not what's happening.

The buttons in their normal state:
[image]

When popped up, the sibling popup button is 'above' the popup
[image]

This is the desired outcome:
[image]

I've managed to find a solution by making the row's TextDirection to RightToLeft, and then reversing the children array, but it's quite hacky and wouldn't work in all cases.

Here's the code for the buttons:

```
class _EntrySheetButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Widget child;

  const _EntrySheetButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  __EntrySheetButtonState createState() => __EntrySheetButtonState();
}

class __EntrySheetButtonState extends State<_EntrySheetButton> {
  bool _menuShown = false;
  final _iconButtonConstraints = BoxConstraints(minHeight: 40, minWidth: 40);

  void _toggleMenu() {
    setState(() {
      _menuShown = !_menuShown;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        fit: StackFit.loose,
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(widget.icon),
            onPressed: _toggleMenu,
            constraints: _iconButtonConstraints,
          ),
          if (_menuShown)
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                elevation: 4,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    widget.child,
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                      onPressed: _toggleMenu,
                      constraints: _iconButtonConstraints,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not include that button as part of your `_menuShown` logic? `if (!_menuShown)`

Comment: Because the button that I want to hide is part of a sibling widget.
I could hide all the buttons from their parent widget, but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: Without some setup, I don't have a way to run your code but I would have thought that you could wrap:`IconButton(...` with `if (!_menuShown) { IconButton(...`

Also, the use of a stack here is interesting and perhaps this is part of the issue. I'd consider using a row and then conditionally show the toggle button - returning an empty `Container()` when it's "hidden"

Comment: Thanks - I found a solution using overlays, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution which is to use Overlays and Overlay Entries, which fixed another problem I was having with stacks (stack overflow child gestures can't be detected https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19445)

More info on Overlays with this excellent article:

https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9